# Javascript passing null to an ExpandoObject field in C# Controller parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net, expando

My Javascript Code

```
$('[step="4"]').click(function () {
//shortened for brevety
var _model = new Object();
_model.ItemDesc.value = 'Descript';
//^ throws an error but gets fixed if removing the .value
_model.ItemQty.num = 1;
_model.ItemQty.unit = 'pcs'

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'CreateItemCallAsync',
        data: _model,
        success: function (msg) {
            status = JSON.stringify(msg);
            alert('Item created successfully!');
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            status = JSON.stringify(msg);
            alert('Failed to create item.');
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

C# Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> CreateItemCallAsync(CreateItemModel item)
{
   //breakpoint here 
   var test = item.ItemDesc;
   var qty = item.ItemQty.num; //getting nulls here
   var unit = item.ItemQty.unit; //getting nulls here
}
```

C# CreateItemModel

```
public class CreateItemModel
{
   public string ItemName { get; set; }
   public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
   public ExpandoObject ItemQty { get; set; }
}
```

JavaScript Object

```
[
  {
     ItemName : 'Item1',
     ItemDesc : 'Descript'
     ItemQty : { num : 5 , unit: 'pcs'}
  },
  {
     ItemName : 'Item2',
     ItemDesc : 'Descript'
     ItemQty : { num : 1 , unit: 'box'}
  }
]
```

From the code above. I have a JavaScript object passed to my C# controller with a `CreateItemModel` parameter that has a field of `ItemQty` as an `ExpandoObject`. However, after passing to my C# controller. the `ItemQty.num` and `ItemQty.unit` are `null`.

With further investigating, before passing the JavaScript object to C# controller. the Objects are successfully populated.

I need `ItemQty` as an `ExpandoObject` because the fields/properites under `ItemQty` is always changing/dynamic

**Questions:**

1. (Bit of off topic) why `_model.ItemDesc.value = 'Descript'` errors? On the other hand `_model.ItemDesc = 'Descript'` runs without error.
2. Why am I getting nulls in `ItemQty` properties?

Comment: Could you show use your receive `JSON` data?

Comment: Add your `CreateItemModel` to the question

Comment: in the ajax request change the data: _model to data: { item: JSON.stringify(_model) } as your api end point is expecting the item object

Comment: For point 1 -  `ItemDesc` is typeof `string` - it does not have a property named `value`

Comment: For point 2. The `DefaultModelBinder` matches the name/value pairs in the request to property names (which do not exist in your model). You need to either create a model to receive the values, or you need to create a custom ModelBinder to read the values from the request and initialize and set you `ExpandoObject` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke thats the problem the. `ItemQty` will not always contain `{ num : 1, unit : 'pcs' }` it can change

Comment: Then you need to create you own custom ModelBinder. (or another option would be to make the property a `IDictionary<string, string>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke `IDictionary<string,string>` on `ItemQty` still returns a `null` in Controller side.

Comment: You need to modify the data you are sending if you want to use a Dictionary (using the default `contentType` as you are doing, then it would be `var _model = {  ItemDesc.value:  'Descript', ItemQty[0].Key: 'num', ItemQty[0].Value: 1,  ItemQty[1].Key: 'unit', ItemQty[1].Value: 'pcs' };`

Answer (score 1):

> (Bit of off topic) why `_model.ItemDesc.value = 'Descript'` errors? On the other hand `_model.ItemDesc = 'Descript'` runs without error.

Because there isn't a property `ItemDesc`,`ItemQty`,`ItemQty`  in original javascript `Object`.

You can try to create an anonymous JSON object for your javascript code.

```
var _model = {     
    ItemDesc: {
        value : "Descript"
    }, 
    ItemQty :{
        num : 1,
        unit :'pcs'
    }
};
```

instead of

```
var _model = new Object();
_model.ItemDesc.value = 'Descript';
_model.ItemQty.num = 1;
_model.ItemQty.unit = 'pcs'
```

your c# model might look like because your currently `ItemDesc` is an object instead of a string value.

> Why am I getting `nulls` in `ItemQty` properties?

Because default ModelBindiner can't find `ExpandoObject` with your `JSON` key `ItemQty` object.

```
public class ItemDesc
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class ItemQty
{
    public int num { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
}

public class CreateItemModel
{
    public ItemDesc ItemDescContext { get; set; }
    public ItemQty ItemQtyContext { get; set; }
}
```